# Android android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2

Tags: android, exception, linker-errors

I have this log

07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at it.android.infoconsumatori.ServiceS$1.handleMessage(ServiceS.java:101)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
07-27 21:42:05.635: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26094):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 21:42:05.640: ERROR/(2695): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error

What is the problem ??

Answer (score 2):

That means you are accessing an item that does not exist. Think of it like this: A cursor has a certain number of rows (the data you want to access), these rows are Zero-indexed, meaning that if there are 10 rows of data, the first row of data is **Index 0**, and the 10th row (the last available value) is **Index 9** not **Index 10** - Index 10 does not exist.

Your problem is exactly due to this, you have a cursor of two rows (index 0 through 1), and you are attempting to access index 2 (a third item that simply isn't there), therefore you get an exception thrown.

Hope that helped.