# How to display images from database

Tags: android, database

I want to display images stored in my database,however my program is throwing an exception(CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 100).
I'm using [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database) and in this tutorial I have managed to insert the images into the database but retreiving them is the problem.
Trying to find answers from google and StackOverflow,I have also come across the following questions.
[Qustion1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165227/cursorindexoutofboundsexception-problemindex-4-requested-with-a-size-of-4)
[Qustion2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850295/android-android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-2-requested-wit).However these questions do not help my case.Any help would be grateful.

Below is my code.

```
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();      
    //select the data
    //while(cursor.moveToFirst());
     cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE, new String[] {DBHelper.C_PHOTOS },
                 null, null, null, null, null);

    //get it as a ByteArray
    byte[] imageByteArray=cursor.getBlob(1);
    //the cursor is not needed anymore
    cursor.close();
     
    //convert it back to an image
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
```

Here is the clase which inserts the images

```
       URL url = new URL("myurl");
             URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
             InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is,128);
             ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(128);
             int current = 0;
             while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                     baf.append((byte) current);
             }
            ContentValues v = new ContentValues();          
            v.put(DBHelper.C_PHOTOS,baf.toByteArray());
            v.put(DBHelper.C_PHOTOS, photoThumbnailUrl);
            db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE, null, v);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It may be better to look into storing just the image path in the database. Then store the image in your images folder.

Comment: Hi,these images are coming from the web,and not in any folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
byte[] imageByteArray = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.C_PHOTOS));
```

Comment: @Brain,thanks for ur reply however this did not stop the exception,i'm currently getting this(02-06 23:09:50.057: E/AndroidRuntime(2384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.guid/com.guid.Image}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 220) from the LogCat.

Comment: Wait... you commented out your `cursor.movetoFirst()`. Try putting one before the `getBlob()`.

Comment: @Brain,Thanks for your sharp eye and expertise, this with moving the cursor to first stopped the exception.

Comment: I would realy be grateful if anyone can help me with this problem,trying to display the images as listview im recieving the following:resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri showing all the images in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Before you get anything from the cursor, I'm pretty sure you have to set the cursor's position with `moveToFirst()`.  This would explain why it thinks its index is -1.  The cursor has not yet been set to the beginning of the list of queried rows.

Also Brian Dupuis' answer describes a far better (and safer) way to get a row column, via `getColumnIndex()`.